# How to prevent document.forms[0].submit() from submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

This is basically my form:

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="checkallfields(); event.preventDefault();">
  <!-- My Stuff -->
</form>
```

And it is the first form on my page. I have client-side field validation, which obviously is stored in the function `checkallfields()`. But the problem is, that the user can be very naughty and open up the console and type `document.forms[0].submit()`, and then the form will still submit.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: even simpler ..user can disable javascript any time they want..plan for it

Comment: I've got that done, just need this to be fixed.

Comment: It's not naughty to bypass client-side validation. It's naughty for the developer to rely on it.

Comment: @user1689607 I never said I was relying on it.

Comment: Well that's super. Then there's nothing to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about the problem, and got my own answer. Tested it in Google Chrome.

```
var i = document.forms.length;
while (i--) {
  document.forms[i].submit = function () {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Does it work for you guys? You can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/think123/ZRuYw/

Comment: and this can be bypassed also. If they have console, they can override it. It is a wasted effort. They just have to run the same loop and override the function.

Comment: @epascarello But for the majority of users who won't know anything about the Chrome devtools or JavaScript, this works pretty well. I don't need 100% security anyways. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: BUT FROM THE POST: *the user can be very naughty and open up the console* If they know how, they can do it. lol.

Comment: @epascarello Ok, ok. I'm sorry. I'm really sorry. But still, they might not know how to change the `document.forms[0].submit()` function method, just like me. I knew `document.forms[0].submit()`, but didn't know I could negate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent it. That is why you need to do serverside validation and that is why you should ALWAYS do serverside validation. The clientside can not be trusted and I do not even need your webpage to submit to your server.

Comment: @think123 This is the practical answer. But just for the sake of curiosity, yes, it's certainly possible. Just don't put your input elements in a form, and have the submit button create the form, submit it, then delete it.

Comment: @st-boost Form still goes to the server so still needs validation there. You could also hijack onsubmit and name it something else. Plenty of ways to hide it, but just need to read the source code to figure out how it is done.

Comment: @epascarello absolutely, just wanted to say that it's technically possible to block that one method.

Answer (score 0):

Just set that function on the document to false.

```
document.forms[0].submit = function () {
  return false;
}
```